# Limitar seleccion de posiciones aleatorias en un array bidimensional

Tags: c

estoy realizando un buscaminas que debe tener como tamaño 10*10 y dentro de este debo ubicar 10 minas en posiciones aleatorias.

Mi problema consiste en que al generar las posiciones aleatorias, estas, en algunos casos se repiten y por tanto se sobrescriben. Es decir, si en la 3ra vuelta del bucle toma la posición (3,7) y luego toma es misma posición en la 5ta vuelta, el valor se sobrescribe y por tanto se descuenta una mina.

¿Como puedo evitar la repetición de posiciones?

Aquí la parte del código donde esta el problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define size 10
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int count=0;
    int bombs=0;
    int x=0;
    int map[size][size];
    for(x=0; x<size; x++) //crea las minas
    {
        i=rand()%11;
        j=rand()%11;
        map[i][j]=1;
        bombs++;
    }
    for (i=0; i<size ; i++ )
        for (j=0; j<size ; j++ )
            if(map[i][j]==1)
            {
                count++;
            }
    printf("bombs = %d\n",count);//verifica la cantidad de bombas
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)//imprime el array
    {
        for(j=0; j<size; j++)
            printf("%d",map[i][j]);
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Esto va a depender de cómo lo quieras hacer: podrías tener un array con las posiciones en las que hay bombas y comprobarlo, o podrías inicializar el mapa de valores a 0 y comprobar antes de cambiar el valor a 1, o podrías verificar la cantidad de bombas cada vez que insertas una y no parar hasta que no estén todas las que necesitas... Como ves hay muchas posibles respuestas, algunas mejores que otras. Deberías buscar una estrategia primero, empezar a programarla y ver si te encuentras algún problema.

Answer (score 2):

Por que no verificas la posición dentro de la matriz antes de asignar la bomba para saber si esta vacía de lo contrario genera una nueva coordenada hasta que la posición este vacía.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define FILAS 10
#define COLUMNAS 20

int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int i=0;
int j=0;
int count=0;
int bombs=0;
int x=0;
int map[FILAS][COLUMNAS];
int numOfBoms = 15; // Numero de bombas a crear

// Inicializamos el array
for (i=0; i < FILAS; i++ )
    for (j=0; j < COLUMNAS; j++ )
      map[i][j]=0;
/*
for(x=0; x<numOfBoms; x++) //crea las minas
{
    i = (rand()%10) + 1;
    j = (rand()%10) + 1;;
    map[i][j]=1;
    bombs++;
}*/

puts("Generacion de bombas");
while (bombs < numOfBoms)
{
    i = (rand() % FILAS);
    j = (rand() % COLUMNAS);

    //  Verificacion de posición  
    if (map[i][j] == 0)
    {
      map[i][j] = 1;
      bombs++;
      printf("Bomba %d en: %d:%d\n", bombs, i, j);
    }
}
puts("");

for (i=0; i < FILAS; i++ )
    for (j=0; j < COLUMNAS; j++ )
        if(map[i][j] == 1)
            count++;

printf("Conteo de bombs = %d\n  ", count); // verifica la cantidad de bombas
for (i = 0; i < COLUMNAS; i++)
  printf("%*d", 3, i);
puts("");

for(i = 0; i < FILAS; i++)//imprime el array
{
    printf("%d ", i);
    for(j = 0; j < COLUMNAS; j++)
      printf("%*d", 3, map[i][j]);

    puts("");
}

return 0;
}
```

Agregue varias variables para controlar el tamaño del tablero mediante Filas y Columnas y la cantidad de minas a generar.

Puedes ver el código compilado en https://repl.it/LKpR/0

Answer (score 2):

La forma mas fácil (a mi juicio):

1. Usamos un mapa de `char`.
2. Creamos el *mapa* de 1 sola dimensión. `char[100]` tiene los elementos en la misma posisición relativa que `char[10][10]`.
3. Icializamos el mapa con `'.'` (puntos). `memset( )` lo hace por nosotros, sin necesidad de bucles ni nada.
4. **Antes** de poner la bomba, comprobamos si en la posición del mapa **ya hay una**.

El resultado viene a ser algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h> // Para 'memset( )`.

#define SIZE 10
#define BOMBS 10

int main( void ) {
  int bombs = BOMBS + 1;
  char map[SIZE * SIZE];
  int pos;

  srand( time( NULL ) );

  // Inicializamos el array con puntos '.'.
  memset( map, '.', SIZE * SIZE );

  // MIENTRAS queden bombas sin esablecer.
  while( --bombs ) {
    // Repetimos HASTA que en el lugar NO HAY bomba.
    do {
      pos = rand( ) % ( SIZE * SIZE );
    } while( map[pos] == 'X' );

    // NO HAY bomba en esa posición. La ponemos.
    map[pos] = 'X';
  }

  // Mostramos el tablero.
  for( pos = 0; pos < ( SIZE * SIZE ); pos += SIZE )
    // SABEMOS que las filas son de longitud fija.
    printf("%.*s\n", SIZE, map + pos );

  return 0;
}
```

Código en Ideone: https://ideone.com/6I3uYT

<sub>**Nota**: Lo de usar `char` es para facilitar mostrar el tablero. Un `char` admite valores de `0` a `127` como mínimo, así que nos sobra para almacenar el número de casillas contiguas libres. O una representación en *bits* del estado de dichas casillas contiguas.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Tienes los siguientes errores**:

- Donde supuestamente creas las minas lo que haces es generar 10 pares aleatorios de [`i`,`j`] que representaran 10 celdas y pones bombas en esas celdas, pero el resto de las celdas no asignas ningún valor, por lo que su contenido sera basura (de hecho al ejecutar tu programa se puede ver esto ya que muchas celdas tienen valores diferentes a 0 y a 1).
- Existe el problema que mencionas de que puedes sobrescribir una mina si se genera de forma aleatoria el mismo par [`i`,`j`].
- Cuentas la cantidad de bombas 2 veces (con `count` y `bombs`) lo cual es redundante, esto no debería ser necesario.

**Te recomiendo hacerlo de la siguiente forma**:

1. Crea tu matriz.
2. Rellena tu matriz de 0.
3. Recorre cada celda de tu matriz y de acuerdo a cierta probabilidad asignas un 1, de esta forma es como si estuvieras poniendo bombas de forma aleatoria en tu tablero.
4. En el caso de asignar una bomba en la celda actual le sumas 1 a `bombs`.
5. Repites desde el paso 2 hasta tener un tablero con la cantidad de bombas que quieres.
6. Imprimes tu tablero.

De acuerdo a los pasos que te comente arriba realice los siguientes cambios en tu código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define size 10

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i = 0, j = 0, bombs = 0, numero_bombas = 10, x;
    int map[size][size];

    // Creamos las bombas y contamos las bombas al mismo tiempo
    while (bombs != 10) {
      bombs = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < size;i++)
          for (j = 0; j<size; j++)
            map[i][j] = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < size;i++)
          for (j = 0; j<size; j++) {
            x = rand() % 100 + 1;

            if (x <= numero_bombas) {
              map[i][j] = 1;
              bombs++;
            }
          }
    }

    // Imprimimos la matriz y la cantidad de bombas que tiene
    printf("bombs = %d\n", bombs);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
            printf("%d ", map[i][j]);
        puts("");
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Notar que en el código agregue la variable `numero_bombas` que representara la cantidad de bombas que deseas poner en el tablero.

El método que uso para poner un número de bombas en el tablero es ir poniendo bombas de forma aleatoria en cada celda de acuerdo a cierta probabilidad, si el tablero tiene un número de bombas diferente a las que se quiere, entonces se vuelve a intentar poner bombas de forma aleatoria hasta que el numero de bombas sea el que se desea.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿ Que tal añadir la posibilidad de indicar exactamente el número de bombas deseadas ? Tal y como lo tienes, igual sale el tablero vacío ... ¡ o totalmente lleno de bombas !

Comment: @Trauma Acabo de modificar el codigo, ahora con la variable `numero_bombas` puedes especificar el numero de bombas que deseas poner en tu tablero.